# String constructor parameter

Tags: java

I came across this question in a Java exercise and I keep getting a memory address printed.

Write code for the following class;

```
public class MyClass 
{ 

}
```

such that the printed result of:

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass("Test Class"); 
System.out.println(cls);
```

will be "Test Class".

(You will need to write the whole class, and use a parameter in the constructor in your answer).

Comment: One thing costs to be noticed. Default implementation of `toString` returns a `getClass().getName()+'@'+Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` but sometimes it looks like memory address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method for the above to work, and add a constructor like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String message;
    public MyClass(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to override the toString() method, such that it returns the value sent in as the parameter of your constructor.